# Replacing TAB in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Below is the query ,I am facing problem in replacing TAB and display into in one column

```
with test as 
(select 'ABC    DEF GHI JKL MNO' str from dual 
) 
select regexp_substr (str, '[\t]+', 1, rownum) split 
  from test 
connect by level <= length (regexp_replace (str, '[\t]+'))  + 1
```

while query is working for comma in pace of tab [^,]

Comment: What is your expected output from the given sample data?

Comment: Expected These value will be in column
SPLIT
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO

Answer (score 1):

You've got several problems in your query:

- your `REGEXP_SUBSTR` returns the tabs instead of the words - you need to invert the character class
- your row number calculation is wrong: `length (regexp_replace (str, '[\t]+'))  + 1` will return as many rows as the string contains tabs; use `length(str) - length(regexp_replace(...))` instead

Here's one version that uses `[[:space:]]` to match tabs (it will also match spaces etc.):

```
with test as 
(select 'ABC  DEH G IJKL' str from dual 
) 
select str, 
  regexp_substr (str, '[^[:space:]]+', 1, rownum) split
from test 
connect by level <= length(str) - length (regexp_replace (str, '[[:space:]]'))
```

The rownum calculation computes the number of whitespace characters by substracting the length of the "cleaned" string from the length of the original string

Comment: @user3655976 You're welcome. If this answers your question, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I get expected result using Replace() fn. The thing is you must be abs sure your string is separated by tab and not smth else. First, I copied and separated string ABC and DEF... by tab in Notepad. Then I copied and run the query in SQL PLUS and get the correct output. Copy/Paste the example below in Notepad to see correct formatting. There is a tab between 'ABC    DEF...':

```
select REPLACE('ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO', chr(9), chr(32) ) str
  from dual
 /

STR
-------------------
ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO
```